# Javascript Revealing Module Pattern and Coffeescript

Tags: javascript, module, design-patterns, coffeescript

I am working on a small script that uses the [Revealing Module Pattern](http://christianheilmann.com/2007/08/22/again-with-the-module-pattern-reveal-something-to-the-world/).

With goold ol' Javascript everything is working fine but I was wondering how to transfer that to Coffeescript.

Take this as an example:

```
// revealing module pattern
var anchorChange4 = function () {

    // this will be a private property
    var config = {
        colors: [ "#F63", "#CC0", "#CFF" ]
    }

    // this will be a public method
    var init = function () {
        var self = this; // assign reference to current object to "self"

        // get all links on the page
        var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
        var size = anchors.length;

        for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            anchors[i].color = config.colors[i];

            anchors[i].onclick = function () {
                self.changeColor(this, this.color); // this is bound to the anchor object
                return false;
            };
        }
    }

    // this will be a public method
    var changeColor = function (linkObj, newColor) {
        linkObj.style.backgroundColor = newColor;
    }

    return {
        // declare which properties and methods are supposed to be public
        init: init,
        changeColor: changeColor
    }
}();
```

equals this in Coffeescript:

```
anchorChange4 = ->
  config = colors: [ "#F63", "#CC0", "#CFF" ]
  init = ->
    self = this
    anchors = document.getElementsByTagName("a")
    size = anchors.length
    i = 0

    while i < size
      anchors[i].color = config.colors[i]
      anchors[i].onclick = ->
        self.changeColor this, @color
        false
      i++

  changeColor = (linkObj, newColor) ->
    linkObj.style.backgroundColor = newColor

  init: init
  changeColor: changeColor
```

`init` and `changeColor` are exposed to the global scope and the Javascript works fine, however the CoffeeScript thing fails because it has no method 'init'.

What needs to be done to convert this Revealing Module Pattern to CoffeeScript?

I am also open for suggestions on how to make it better. ;-)

Thanks,
Dominik

Comment: No need to use a `while` loop and increment `i` manually; use `for i in [0...size]`

Answer (score 2):

The difference between the CoffeeScript and JavaScript versions is that the function defined in the CoffeeScript version is never being called. In the JS version the function's return value is being put in anchorChange4, but in the CS version the variable gets the function itself.

You can change this by adding some parentheses to the first and last lines of the CoffeeScript code:

```
anchorChange4 = (->
    ...
    changeColor: changeColor)()
```

Comment: That solves one problem, I am able to call anchorChange4.changeColor from the outside. :-)
One problem remains: I can't call the method changeColor from within init as soon I work with the Coffeescript.

The Javascript allows me to do this with `var self = this;` and `self.changeColor`

Comment: This answer could alternatively be written as `anchorChange4 = do -> ...`

Comment: @dmnkhhn The `self = this` stuff is identical to the JavaScript. How are you calling `init`?

Comment: `anchorChange.init()` in the main html file after the compiled coffeescript has been loaded.

The strange thing is: Within anchorChange4() I can call the method as soon as I write `publicMethod: privateMethod` at the end. If not, the method is not executed.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to return a new JSON object exposing those methods, then the final line should be...

```
{
  init: init
  changeColor: changeColor
}
```

To return a JSON object instead of just changeColor. Remember, coffee returns the last statement of execution from a function, you had two lines you wanted returned.

Comment: Travis is correct; use curly braces when returning an object literal from a function. I believe there's an open issue to discuss changing this.